# Scale camera in libGDX not save dimensions

Tags: android, camera, libgdx

I want to use map in my app and do move, scale and rotation on it using `libGDX` library, I'm using this code to scale camera in android:

```
public class MyGdxGame extends ApplicationAdapter implements GestureDetector.GestureListener {
    SpriteBatch batch;
    Texture texture;
    Sprite sprite;
    OrthographicCamera camera;

    @Override
    public void create() {
        batch = new SpriteBatch();

        camera = new OrthographicCamera(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
        texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("map.jpg"));
        sprite = new Sprite(texture);
        sprite.setPosition(-sprite.getWidth() / 2, -sprite.getHeight() / 2);

        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(new GestureDetector(this));
    }

    @Override
    public void render() {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        camera.update();
        batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
        batch.begin();
        sprite.draw(batch);
        batch.end();
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        batch.dispose();
        texture.dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean pan(float x, float y, float deltaX, float deltaY) {
        camera.translate(-deltaX, deltaY);
        return false;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean zoom(float initialDistance, float distance) {
        float scale = initialDistance / distance;
        camera.zoom = scale;
        return false;
    }



}
```

It is zooming correctly, but when I touch up and try to zoom again it begin zoom from scale = 1.
How can zoom the cam and save its status?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any experience in zooming with LibGDX, but an idea would be saving the `initialDistance` in a variable and use it instead of the original one (expect for the first time to get the initial value).

```
@Override
public boolean zoom(float initialDistance, float distance) {
    if(savedDistance == 0)
        savedDistance = initialDistance

    float scale = savedDistance / distance;
    camera.zoom = scale;
    return false;
}
```

If this doesn't help, reading the [docs](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/input/GestureDetector.GestureAdapter.html#zoom-float-float-) or looking into the [source code](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/input/GestureDetector.java) could give you an idea.